# CSS Nested Div Print Problem: Text bunches at top of second page

Tags: asp.net, css

Here's the HTML and inline CSS I'm using currently:

```
<div style="width: 975px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0;">
        <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px;">Test Group 1</span></div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 8px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
    </div>
<div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
    margin: 0; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 3px double;">
    <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
        display: block; position: absolute;">
        $0.00</div>
    <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
        position: absolute;">
        $0.00</div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
    margin: 0; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; border-bottom: 3px double;">
    <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
        display: block; position: absolute;">
        $0.00</div>
    <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
        display: block; position: absolute;">
        $0.00</div>
    <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
        display: block; position: absolute;">
        $0.00</div>
</div>
</div><div style="width: 975px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: left; display: block;
    margin: 0; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 975px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    display: block; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
        <span style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 130px;">L GROUP</span></div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 8px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 975px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    display: block; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 390px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 324px; text-align: right; width: 60px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            <span id="lnkInvoice17">828</span></div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 264px; text-align: right; width: 35px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            5.00000%</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: left; padding-left: 197px; width: 60px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            7/14/2010</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 8px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00**</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 975px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    display: block; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 390px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 324px; text-align: right; width: 60px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            <span id="lnkInvoice18">828</span></div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $165,165.12</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 975px; clear: both; float: left; text-align: left; display: block;
    margin: 0; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is basically a bunch of nested DIVS serving as an expandable/collapsable div structure. I removed all of the functionality for the purpose of printing this out. The problem, however, is that the page shows up in print preview perfectly... until it needs to page break onto the next page. The 2nd page has the rest of the text all jubbled up at the top of the page:

[image]

Anyone have any clue as to what's going on? I'm assuming it's a FLOAT or INLINE/BLOCK problem, but I can't seem to figure out which.

Comment: You should maybe post this on jsFiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB2qd/ - there ya go.

Comment: Only way to debug this code is to shoot it first and then dissect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this HTML

```
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 975px; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0;">
        <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px;">Test Group 1</span>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 8px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 975px; float: left; text-align: left; display: block;
    margin: 0; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 975px; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    display: block; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
        <span style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 130px;">L GROUP</span></div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 8px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 3px double;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 975px; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    display: block; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 390px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 324px; text-align: right; width: 60px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            <span id="lnkInvoice17">828</span>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 264px; text-align: right; width: 35px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            5.00000%
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: left; padding-left: 197px; width: 60px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            7/14/2010
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 8px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block;
            position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 80px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; width: 70px; display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00**
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 975px; float: left; text-align: left; margin: 0;
    display: block; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 390px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 324px; text-align: right; width: 60px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            <span id="lnkInvoice18">828</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 175px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 90px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: right; width: 70px;
            display: block; position: absolute;">
            $165,165.12
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 975px; float: left; text-align: left; display: block;
    margin: 0; background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <div style="width: 384px; float: left; height: 20px; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #BEE0F7; width: 165px; height: 20px; float: right;
        padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #CFF5CE; width: 166px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #F0D3D3; width: 253px; height: 20px; float: right;
        margin: 0; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this CSS

```
<script type="text/css">
 .clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  }

.clearfix {
   display: inline-block;
 }

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This actually seems to work for the most part. The only problem is on the second page... all of the actual lines I have that separate out the totals are gone along with the lettering on the left that describes each line.